# Retrieve nested list (matrix) from gRPC in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, grpc, protoc, grpc-node

I'm using `gRPC` with `NodeJs` and the response I want is this (example in JS format):

```js
[
  ['aa1', 0, 0],
  ['aa2', 0, 0],
  ...
  ['aaN', 0, 0],
]
```

Is a list inside another list. Like a 2-Dimensional array or a matrix.

The problem here is I haven't seen examples returning a list inside an object without key/value fields, so I don't know how to create the `.proto` file.

Now I have something like this:

```proto
message Response{
  repeated ResponseData data = 1;
}
message ResponseData {
  repeated string field1 = 1;
  repeated uint32 field2 = 2;
  repeated uint32 field3 = 3;
}
```

And into node file to get and read the data I have something like:

```js
client.getData(request, {}, (err, response)=> {
  var result = response.getDataList();
  // ^^^^^^^ here I want to get the matrix
}
```

Also I've tried with:

```js
var result = response.getDataList();
result.forEach(element => {
  console.log("element 1 = ",element.getField1List())
  console.log("element 2 = ",element.getField2List())
  console.log("element 3 = ",element.getField3List())
})
```

But arrays returned from `element.getFieldXList()` are empty.

Also from server I'm sending this test matrix:

```js
[["0",0,0],["1",1,1],["2",2,2],["3",3,3]]
```

Any help is apreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Using `console.log(JSON.stringify(result))` the output is:

```json
[{"wrappers_":null,"arrayIndexOffset_":-1,"array":[[],[],[]],"pivot_":1.7976931348623157e+308,"convertedPrimitiveFields_":{}},{"wrappers_":null,"arrayIndexOffset_":-1,"array":[[],[],[]],"pivot_":1.7976931348623157e+308,"convertedPrimitiveFields_":{}},{"wrappers_":null,"arrayIndexOffset_":-1,"array":[[],[],[]],"pivot_":1.7976931348623157e+308,"convertedPrimitiveFields_":{}},{"wrappers_":null,"arrayIndexOffset_":-1,"array":[[],[],[]],"pivot_":1.7976931348623157e+308,"convertedPrimitiveFields_":{}}]
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(JSON.stringify(result))` inside the `getData` callback and show us the output?

Comment: Yes! Updated question with the `console.log()` result.

Comment: Oh ok, so this is definitely an issue on the grpc server side as the elements in each `array` are empty. I thought you had problems mapping it in your nodejs code. As I have no experience with grpc I can't help here, sorry :)

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for your advice anyway. I will take a look to the server but now it sends this object: `[["0",0,0],["1",1,1],["2",2,2],["3",3,3]]` so should be ok, so maybe the problem is with the `proto` structure and trying to map this list...

Answer (score 1):

The protobuf message definition in the question describes an object that contains a list of objects, each of which has three fields, which each have a list of primitive values. However, you said that you tried to send a list of lists, which is a very different structure. To send a message, you need to provide an object with the same structure. For the message types provided, that would look something like this:

```js
response = {
  data = [
    {
      field1: ["0"],
      field2: [0],
      field3: [0]
    },
    {
      field1: ["1"],
      field2: [1],
      field3: [1]
    },
    // ...
  ]
}
```

If you want to represent something more similar to the list of lists in the question, you probably want the inner fields of the `ResponseData` message to not be `repeated`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I will take a look. But I want a list of list. Is this a solution for an object list? I'm looking for a matriz solution, as the first example.

Comment: You can't directly represent a list of lists in Protobuf. You need to translate it to some kind of message format like you have in the question.

Comment: I didn't know that. Then I will check your solution tomorrow. Thanks a lot!